# Show that $X+Y$ and $X/Y$ are independent.

Tags: expectation, moment-generating-functions

Here's my problem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be iid with a common pdf

$f(t) = exp(-t),$ if $t > 0$,

$0$ otherwise.

Show that $X+Y$ and $X/Y$ are independent.

Here's what I'm thinking:

$X+Y$ and $X/Y$ are independent if $M(t_1,t_2) = E[e^{t_1(X+Y) + t_2(X/Y)}] = E[e^{t_1X}]E[e^{t_1Y}]E[e^{t_2(X/Y)}]$, i.e. the joint mgf of $X+Y$ and $X/Y$ is equal to the product of the individual mgfs $M_{X+Y}(t)$ and $M_{X/Y}(t)$.

We can easily show that the mgf $M_{X+Y}(t) = M_X(t)M_Y(t) = E[e^{tX}]E[e^{tY}] = e^{-(x+y)} (x>0,y>0)$, which leaves me to solve for $M_{X/Y}(t) = E[e^{t_2(X/Y)}]$. But since $X/Y$ is a fraction, it remains difficult to solve.

Am I doing this the right way? Is there a better way? If not, how do I complete this?

Thanks

Comment: $X|X+Y\sim U(0,X+Y)$ so it's obvious that $X/Y$ is independent of $X+Y$.

Comment: So let me make sure I understand: you're saying that given X+Y, X must be somewhere between 0 and X+Y, so X|X+Y is a uniformly random variable in (0,X+Y). Then the question is whether X/Y is independent of X+Y. But I'm not sure how you get that X/Y is indep of X+Y...

Comment: $\frac X Y=\frac {\frac X{X+Y}}{\frac Y{X+Y}}$ and numerator and denominator are both $U(0,1)$ adding up to $1$ - independent of $X+Y$.

Comment: Wow. How do you come up with this sort of proof? Seems like magic. Thanks AS

Btw is it not supposed to involve the given pdf exp(-t)? Thx again

Comment: The numerator and denominator are $U(0,1)$ because $X,Y$ are i.i.d. exponentials. To prove that fact (if you never did before) you need to use given pdfs.

Comment: Cool fact: the above suffices to show that $(XY)^Z\sim U(0,1)$ for $X,Y,Z$ i.i.d. $U(0,1)$

Comment: @A.S. Post as answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the variables are independent if you can show that
$$
E[e^{t_1 (X+Y) + t_2 (X/Y)}]= E[e^{t_1 (X+Y)}] E[e^{t_2 (X/Y)}] . 
$$
This does not hold unconditionally and its validity relies on the hypothesis at hand. A.S. gave a beautiful proof in the comment. Alternatively you can reason as you where doing:

First compute

\begin{align}
E[e^{t_1 (X+Y) + t_2 (X/Y)}]&= \int_0^\infty \!\! \!dx \int_0^\infty \!\! \! dy e^{-x(1-t_1 -t_2/y) - y(1-t_2)} \\
 &= \int_0^\infty \!\! \! dy \frac{e^{-y(1-t_1)}}{1-t_1 -t_2/y}
\end{align}

Now use the substitution $y(1-t_1)=z$ to obtain

$$
M(t_1,t_2) = \frac{1}{(1-t_1)^2}\int_0^\infty \!\! \!dz  \frac{e^{-z}}{1-t_2/z}
$$

Now you can check that
\begin{align}
E[e^{t_1 (X+Y)}] E[e^{t_2 (X/Y)}] &= \int_0^\infty \!\! \!dx \int_0^\infty \!\! \! dy e^{-x(1-t_1) -y(1-t_2)} \int_0^\infty \!\! \!dx \int_0^\infty \!\! \! dy e^{-x(1-t_2/y)-y} \\
&= \frac{1}{(1-t_1)^2}\int_0^\infty \!\! \!dy  \frac{e^{-y}}{1-t_2/y}
\end{align}

and you are done.

By the way, note that the MGF of your exponential distribution is $1/(1-t_1)$ (for $t_1 <1$).

Comment: I did not assume what I was trying to prove. I said, if I can show that the joint mgf equals the product of the individual mgfs, then we have proven it. Where did I assume what I was trying to prove?

Comment: You are right I misread. Edited

Answer (score 0):

Let $U=X+Y$ and $V=\frac XY$. It is clear that $U\sim\operatorname{Exp}(2)$. If $v>0$ then $vY\sim\operatorname{Exp}\left(\frac1v\right)$, so
$$\mathbb P(V \leqslant v) = \mathbb P(X\leqslant vY) = \frac1{1+\frac1v} = \frac v{1+v}.$$
Therefore $U=g(X)$ and $V=h(Y)$ where
\begin{align}
g(x) &= 2x\\
h(y) &= 1+e^{\frac12 y},
\end{align}
and hence $\sigma(U)\subset\sigma(X)$, $\sigma(V)\subset\sigma(Y)$. Since $X$ and $Y$ were assumed to be independent, it follows that $U$ and $V$ are independent.